# pandas.to_sql function does not convert dtype as expected

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to export a pandas df to SQL server using the following code:

```
dtypedict={"column1": sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=50), 
                   "column2": sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=50),
                   'column3': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=50),
                   'column4': sqlalchemy.types.INTEGER(),
                   'column5': sqlalchemy.types.Date(),
                   'column6': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=50),
                   'column7': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=50),
                   'column8': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=50), 
                   'column9': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=50)}

staging.columns = staging.columns.str.replace(' ','_')
staging.fillna('', inplace=True)

server = 'SV' 
database = 'DB' 
username = 'U' 
password = 'PW'  
cnxn = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(cnxn))

staging.to_sql('Staging_table', schema='dbo', con=engine, chunksize=50, index=False, if_exists='replace', dtype=dtypedict, method='multi')
```

For some reason, I keep getting the following error:

```
('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'No EQ' to data type int. (245) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

This 'No EQ' value appears in column2. I do not understand why the function attempts to convert a nvarchar to int as the dtype specified is varchar. Examing the column type in Azure Data Studio, varchar is also correctly parsed as sql type for column2. The df dtype is object.

Unfortunately I have to use the old SQL server driver and cannot download a recent ODBC one due to permission restrictions.

Anyone has suggestions how to fix this?

I double checked whether the column names in the dict are named correctly and they are as everything resolves to true:

```
col_list = staging.columns.to_list()

for col in col_list:
    for key in dtypedict.items():
        if col in key:
            print('True for ' + col)
```

Comment: Double-check that the column names in `dtypedict` exactly match those in the DataFrame. If we include a column name in `dtype=` that does not exist in the DataFrame then `.to_sql()` silently ignores it.

Comment: @GordThompson everything seems to match, I used the code in my edited post to verify and everything resolves to true.

Comment: What column names and datatypes do you get from the database if you use from_sql? Do they also match with this?

Comment: @rfkortekaas the columns are imported with the correct dtypes as they are exported, so corresponding with the columns and sqlalchemy types initially stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the object dtype of the df or in the to_sql process didn't work out for columns that seemingly contained integer values AND string values and were misinterpreted as int columns even though dtypes were specified with the dict.

I converted all combined dtype columns with the .astype(str) function and now to_sql works for all columns!

Comment: can you show how you did that. I am having similar problem.